# This javascript concatenation worked once for me, but is this always acceptable javascript?

Tags: javascript, arguments, concatenation

In one of my site's functions (**myFunction**), I had four variables that I needed passed to another function (an Ajax function that has a general format - **function GeneralFunction ('id1', 'id2', param1, param2, param3)**  ).

At this point, I need to keep this general format, but **myFunction** had too many parameters to pass to **GeneralFunction**. So I concatenated as follows:

```
function myFunction(a, b, c, d) {
    //Lots of code then
    var param3 = c + "," + d;
    GeneralFunction('id1', 'id2', a, b, param3);
}
```

I then explode param3 and process what was c and d in the php file to which **GeneralFunction** passes param3....this works fine.

However, my question is as follows...is the following code always acceptable? I thought I would save a step by rewriting **myFunction** as:

```
function myFunction(a, b, c, d) {
    //Lots of code then
    GeneralFunction('id1', 'id2', a, b, c + "," + d);
}
```

c and d are concatenated as they are passed to **GeneralFunction**. Although this worked as intended, and the online lint js checker I use (http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) did not detect any errors, is concatenating (or performing any kind of operation, arithmetic, concatenation, etc.) and passing an argument - simultaneously - a generally acceptable protocol?

I did not find much in my google search, and just because it worked once does not in my opinion mean it is always going to work!

Comment: In your specific case, I'd suggest to pass an array: `GeneralFunction('id1', 'id2', a, b, [c, d])` and let your ajax function handle how to serialize this so that it can be properly decoded on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is honestly not very advisable.  Not only is the code itself rather unhygienic to look at, but you'll lose type information for the extra parameters.  Consider, for example, if `c` and `d` were a `bool` and `number`, respectively:

```
var c = true,
    d = 3;

var combined = c + ',' + d; // "true,3"

combined.split(','); // ["true", "3"]
```

Notice that you now have two strings (`"true"`, and `"3"`), rather than your initial values.

There are other issues as well.  For example, if either `c` or `d` is a string with commas in it, you'll end up with unexpected results on the other side:

```
var c = 'hello,world',
    d = 'foo,bar';

var combined = c + ',' + d; // "hello,world,foo,bar"

combined.split(','); // ["hello", "world", "foo", "bar"]
```

At this point, it's impossible to tell which "parts" were originally from `c` vs. from `d`.  So now you have to introduce some escaping for commas... yuck.

The ideal solution for this would be to simply change your strict 4-parameter requirement.  If this isn't possible, however, I would instead recommend passing extra variables in an array:

```
function myFunction(a, b, c, d) {
    //Lots of code then
    GeneralFunction('id1', 'id2', a, b, [c, d]);
}
```

With this approach, you'll have no loss of type info, and it'll be easier to retrieve the values on the other side.

Comment: "This is honestly not very advisable"—should have told Douglas Crockford that before he headed down the JSON route… :-)

Comment: Excellent answer....to respond to your first point, not worried about the unhygienic appearance, just care about speed since the code will be seen by my eyes only and I am used to reading text that looks like gibberish to the untrained eye (I was a chemist for 15 years :)  I will respond to your other point in a couple of minutes...going to try your suggestion

Comment: I tried your code...I can see its utility but I will need more work to get it right...I should have added in my question that only strings are passed to GeneralFunction(), but I can see how I was wrong in that booleans would not work properly

Comment: Ahh, wasn't aware of the string-only constraint. In that case I would recommend still going with the array, but serializing/deserializing it with `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.  E.g., `var param3 = JSON.stringify([c, d]));`. This will safely handle the various corner cases.  E.g., `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(['hello,world', 'foo,bar'])); // ["hello,world", "foo,bar"]`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is performing any kind of operation (arithmetic, concatenation, etc.) and passing an argument - simultaneously - a generally acceptable protocol?

Yes, totally acceptable. It's quite rare actually that only plain variables are passed to a function, most often the arguments consist of arbitrary expressions. Notice they don't happen "simultaneously", but the arguments are evaluated left-to-right and then their result values are passed to the function.

Comment: "It's quite rare actually that only plain variables are passed to a function, most often the arguments consist of arbitrary expressions". I strongly disagree with this. Passing arbitrary expressions that require parsing is error prone, inefficient, and almost always unnecessary.

Comment: @jmar777—Not sure about that. Maybe "rare" is an overstatement ("common" might be better), but looking through say jQuery (because it happens to be there, not for any other reason) there are many calls using expressions, such as `this.pushStack( j >= 0 && j < len ? [ this[j] ] : [] );` and `matcherFromTokens((tokens = tokens.slice(j)))` and `jQuery._data( elem, "globalEval", !refElements || jQuery._data( refElements[i], "globalEval"));`.  So it might be unnecessary (you can always assign the result to a variable and pass that), but it's convenient to just "pass" the expression instead.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Bergi. What I mean is that the argument is not a "finished/final" argument in that it is evaluated within the parentheses of the called function

Comment: @RobG Ahh, I see what you're talking about now. My objection wasn't to having an expression in the function call, it was to building out some string-serialized expression that got parsed on the other side.  I.e., `fn(1 + 2)` is fine, but `fn('1+2')` and then parsing `'1+2'` on the other side is sketchy.  My apologies for misunderstanding you, though.

Comment: @jmar777: RobG's examples are quite advanced actually :-) I counted even literals as non-variable-expressions - you wouldn't write `var one=1; fn(one)`

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <script>
        function fun1(a,b,c,d)
        {
            alert(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d);
            var demo=c+","+d;
            fun2(a,b,demo);
        }
        function fun2(a,b,d)
        {
            alert(a+" "+b+" "+d);
        }
    </script>

    <body>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fun1(1,2,3,4)">Call</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

If "," (Comma) not work in concatenation use # or other sign.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I know about concatenation but I need to know if this method will always work

Comment: Yes.! at the my experience it work always. i already used in past